# Heroku Logs Insight

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, heroku

My Ruby on Rails app was running smoothly until yesterday.

When ever I try to open my Heroku App it gives me a "Application Error" message and when I check my logs I get this message below.

```
[36m2013-09-10T17:42:34.393159+00:00 app[web.1]: [0m Connecting to database 
specified by DATABASE_URL
[36m2013-09-10T17:42:34.846457+00:00 app[web.1]: [0m Exiting
[36m2013-09-10T17:42:34.849786+00:00 app[web.1]: [0m /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.
0.0/gems/devise-3.1.0/lib/devise/rails/routes.rb:440:in `raise_no_secret_key': 
Devise.secret_key was not set. Please add the following to your Devise 
initializer: (RuntimeError)
```

Has anyone encountered this?  What does the error mean?

Comment: Have you included all of the error message?  There should be more instructions below it that tell you what to do.  Please add that part.

Answer (score 3):

A discussion about that error here:
https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/issues/2554

Follow the error log instructions in your post.  Add the following to your Devise initializer:

```
config.secret_key = '-- secret key --'
```

Comment: There we go. This fixed the problem. Though I just wondered why it used to work perfectly, but now it demands a secret key.

Comment: Could you mark this response as correct if it solved your problem?